# How to make excel SUMUP values of multiple rowkeys in a two-dimensional lookup to return sumed up values in a corresponding cell

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-office-2013, vlookup, lookup

So I have this challenge with a set of data arrangement and by merging the VLOOKUP and MATCH strings I was able to get my result but there is a little hiccup!

Pasted below is the merged string that looks up and match each Outlet Owner on column A with each corresponding Product on row `A1:G1`

```
=VLOOKUP($I2,$A$1:$G$21,MATCH(K$1,$A$1:$G$1,0),FALSE)
```

This is my data sheet:

[image]

As it is now, I'm stuck cos the formula only returns one (the first in the list I think) of the many available figures in situations where a row-key appears more than once in the range lookup. So I'd really appreciate if someone could help with how I can still add a SUMUP string to the above formula such that it'll add up all multiple row-keys and return the total. For instance in my case the final string should add up all figures under each product for Samson, Juliet, Matthew and the likes that has more than one Outlets and return their totals in corresponding cells in the summary section.

> Note: I used `VLOOKUP` because my headers in the summary section (destination sheet) aren't arranged in the same way as the table for lookup (source sheet). My real data sheet has an enormously long range of headers and I can't waste precious time and energy to start arranging columns to look alike in both source and destination sheets!

Comment: Both answers below do not care the order of the column headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX(($B$1:$E$1=K$1)*($A$2:$A$21=$J2)*$B$2:$E$21,))
```

The INDEX() builds an array of values with 0 where ever the header and row does not match the criteria.

[image]

As per your edited answer, to show that the order does not matter:

[image]

---

To make the formula Plug and play use this:

```
=SUM(INDEX(($C$1:$G$1=K$1)*($A$2:$A$21=$I2)*$C$2:$G$21,))
```

Put it is K2.  Then drag over and down.

[image]

Comment: @HakimBalogun  See the edit.  The formula on bottom is ready to just plug in K2 and drag across and down.

Comment: @HakimBalogun now you need to choose one to mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer of your choice.  It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VLOOKUP` to retrieve single items, calculating sum requires `SUM`, `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS`, for your case this formula will work:

`=SUMIF($A$2:$A$15,$H2,INDEX($B$2:$E$15,0,MATCH(I$1,$B$1:$E$1)))`

Explaining it a bit:

- `MATCH` selects the index of the right column
- `INDEX` selects the right column (note the `0` as row index)
- `SUMIF` calculates the sum for the actual owner name

[image]

Comment: I've been battling with this all day but I don't seem to find my way around the 'INDEX' syntax. If the 'SUMIF' syntax can be merged into my 'VLOOKUP' formula just as you did with your 'INDEX' suggestion please show me how. I have little knowledge of modifying functions. Thanks!

Comment: @HakimBalogun VLOOKUP will not work in this situation, as it only returns one value while the INDEX returns the whole row.  What is wrong specifically with the above solution?

Comment: I guess I'm not doing it right, it keeps returning the #REF! error.

Comment: Why do you want to use `VLOOKUP`??? please update your question with desired output to make clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: It's ok @Máté Juhász, the INDEX now works fine and it solved the problem. Thanks!